# SimpleDateFormat parse returns nothing when working with time

Tags: java, android, datetime

Am trying to convert a `Date` String to Date but `SimpleDateFormat.parse` returns nothing when I add the time.

This is the Date String:

```
String dateInString = news.getDate();
Log.e(TAG, "Date in String: " + dateInString);

Date in String: 2015-08-19T06:21:59+01:00 //Result
```

When I do:

```
DateFormat format
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);        
Date date;
    try {

        date = format.parse(dateInString);
        Log.e(TAG, "Formatted date: " + date);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get the result: `Formatted date: Wed Aug 19 01:00:00 GMT+01:00 2015`

If I add the time to SimpleDateFormat:

```
DateFormat format
        = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

the code doesn't even get past the try and no exception is thrown.Nothing just gets printed.

I have tried adding the `TimeZone` with no luck:

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC+01"); //also tried GMT+1:00, UTC+1:00 and UTC
    DateFormat format
            = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
    format.setTimeZone(timeZone);

    try {

        date = format.parse(dateInString);
        Log.e(TAG, "Formatted date: " + date);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX` pattern should work for your format. And setting timezone can be omitted since it is defined in date/time string.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I get a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown pattern character 'X'` using your suggestion. Andy's worked but I don't know why he deleted his comment

Comment: The 'X' is available since Java 1.7 !

Comment: Why then am I getting the exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern sed for SimpleDataFormat is incorrect, use this one:

```
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Notice the pattern is slightly different, I've added a T text separating date and time and also the `ZZZZZ` which says there is timezone there.

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX",Locale.ENGLISH);
```

'X' flag is available since 1.7 and it represents Timezone.

All available flags are described here
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Take a look at the comments for the question

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are several ways to do this. In addition to Arturo's answer, this also works:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.English);
```